# Socket.IO: How to end socket.on() event early?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to communicate between my client and server.

I was wondering if there's a way to stop a req/res on the server-side early?

For example,

let's say client does `socket.emit("Testing", 4)`

On server.js

```
socket.on("Testing", (number) => {

 if (number === 4) {
   //end this event
 };

 console.log("The Testing Event Number is: " + number);

});
```

How do I stop the server socket.on event early?

I've tried putting return, exit, break, but nothing works. I remember that for req/res with Express, using return ends the request early, but it's not the case for socket.io

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "end the request"?  A return in the socket handler function would stop execution of that function on the server... but is there something else you are trying to stop? An asynchronous operation maybe?

Comment: @Matt It's so weird. I tried it again and you're right it stops it...not sure why it didn't before...but thanks for answering the question!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt for answering. For some reason when I tried using return before, it didn't end the handler, but it did this time...